# Plugin works on emulator but not through PhoneGap desktop app ? AdMobPro

Tags: android, cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I have created a test project and added the plugin AdMobPro through this link : https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro.

There, is a step by step guide on how to install and add the plugin to a new project. This all works fine, finally. I run it in the emulator, the ads pop up no problem. Click through the interface, show interstitial ads and so on no problem either.

The problem occurs when I try and use the PhoneGap desktop app to serve the app to my device. I do this from the PhoneGap app on my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (I named the phone in case someone has came across this problem before on this device), typed in the server address. The app pops up, alerts working fine on button click etc (testing purposes) but none of the ads work.

To clarify, the ads show in the Android emulator, but not when serving to the PhoneGap app. Any one have any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried with another plugin? For me this one is working fine:  https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova. There is also demo project here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-demo

Comment: yeah the first link you sent I have been through those steps before. All works fine on the emulator, but when I serve via phonegap desktop app :(

Comment: And are the ads being shown in the compiled app? (`cordova run android --device`)

Comment: no ive just tried that and nothing is showing ? :/

Comment: i appended an alert when clicking the button and even thats not working

Comment: Maybe you can try with compiled app to see if the error is with phonegap app (most probable...)

Comment: @David I tried with compiled app, i.e cordova run android --device, and it runs just the plugin doesnt seem to be working. I appended an alert to the button click before it goes off to do the adMob stuff and that doesnt fire. If there are errors where would they be outputted ? To the cmd prompt ? Is there a way to see console logs from the compiled app ? I looked at jsconsole.com but this isn't the best, i would rather something local and reliable. Appreciate the time and help btw

Comment: In fact you can use chrome dev tools to debug your app and see if admob and other plugins are being added & load. Once I faced a problem that the plugin was added but it wasn't loaded by cordova. I ended removing the platform and adding it again (`cordova platform rm androd && cordova platform add android`)

Comment: @David I can't use chrome dev tools as the plugin doesn't work on browser ....

Comment: chrome dev tools to inspect the app in the device (chrome://inspect, open the app in the device and debug your app in device)

Comment: Yep tried that, but says AdMob is undefined.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? I normally use https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova, is with the one I can help you

Comment: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro thats the one Im currently using. Ill try to implement the one you have pointed me at and get back to you :)

Comment: @David i get build errors as soon as I add the plugin. I have created a new project and fetched the latest admob plugin but it doesnt build as soon as i install the plugin. Any ideas ? I thought it was a version issue, but if installed android and got the plugin, i thought they would have installed the latest version ? And be the same version ? The error is error:retrieving parent for item : no resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'. hmmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110409/discussion-between-david-and-thatoneguy).

Answer (score 1):

The PhoneGap Desktop App works as local web server that you can use with the PhoneGap Developer App to preview your code without creating a separate build.

The reason that you're not seeing the AdMobPro plugin working in the PhoneGap Developer App is because the PhoneGap Developer App only supports the core [PhoneGap plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/plugin-apis/).

Comment: That is what I needed to know. Annoying but helpful, thank you

Comment: There is method to preview third party / custom plugins in the PhoneGap Developer App, it requires you to build your own custom version of the PhoneGap Developer App with the third party / custom plugins bundled.

Refer to the [Adding Custom Plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer) section.